# Python Requests Cookies not stored

Tags: python, python-requests, session-cookies

I am trying to login to a page using Python requests (2.10.0).

**Code**:

```
payload = {
    'user_login': 'amitg.ind@gmail.com',
    'user_pass': 'xxx',
    'rememberme': '1'
}
with requests.session() as sess:
    resp = sess.post(URL_LOGIN, data=payload)
    print resp.cookies
```

This should have returned multiple cookies. When I see in Chrome developer tools, I see the following:

[image: Cookies Post Login]  [image]

However, when I print it on console, I see only the last cookie. Rest all are lost. The same login password works in browser. Due to this, subsequent request from same session fails.

*RequestsCookieJar [Cookie wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check for some.domain]*.

Why are the other cookies not preserved in session. All other subsequent requests doesn't recognize the login and I suspect its because of the missing cookies.

**Could anyone help please?**

Comment: You sure your post is correct?

Comment: Given by responses - No. New to python requests and web scraping. If you could give me a hint - I will correct it.

Comment: I would need to see the url to monitor the request

Comment: Its http://sold.watch/just-sold/

Comment: My question is that when we use session.post() and its successful (200) - Shouldn't it persists all cookies as shown in Developers Tools? Why are cookies not getting stored in session? They do so when I login using a browser.

Comment: Try adding `"wp-submit":"Log In"` and a user-agent, also it is `log` and `pwd` not user_login and user_pass

Comment: Thanks @Padraic - I was using the 'id' attribute but name was to be used. Thanks for that. wp-submit was not required. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Padraic - I was using the 'id' attribute but 'name' was to be used. Thanks for that. wp-submit was not required. Thanks again.